# .NET Validators doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have simple page Page.aspx like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server">
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phNewAddress" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

In code behind is:

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  AddressDetail xControl = (AddressDetail)Page.LoadControl("AddressDetail.ascx");
  phNewAddress.Controls.Add(xControl);
}
```

AddressDetail.ascx is:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="address_name" runat="server" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="address_name" ErorMessage="Required" ValidationGroup="save">*
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

  <asp:DropDownList ID="address_state" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" /> 

  <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

DropDownList address_state is binding from datasource.

Now. After page is loaded and I press Save button, validator doesn't work.
But if I change DropDownList, so fire postback, and then press Save button, validator works fine.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing validation controls work with viewstate, Move the  below code from Page_load event to Page_Init event  and see if it works.

```
protected override void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  AddressDetail xControl = (AddressDetail)Page.LoadControl("AddressDetail.ascx");
  phNewAddress.Controls.Add(xControl);
}
```

Comment: I tested your sample code above, the validation seems to be working fine on page load. Are you sure  the validation isn't getting disabled from somewhere else?